# Cannot access global variable defined in html from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, scope, global

On my Html page i define a global variable, as in this example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var users=2;
</script>
```

However when i try to access it in another javascript file, like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    start();
});

function start() {
    alert(users);
}
```

I get an error message saying: users is not defined. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's global for *that* file

Comment: Try putting `var users=2;` in with the `jQuery` code, right above `start();`

Comment: Try `window.onload = start;`

Comment: Include the javascript file in HTML after 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var users=2;
</script>

Comment: how do you import those scripts/files?, please provide the full code